# vscode How to Hot Swap/Reload a Maven webapp project using Community Server Connectors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a legacy maven web app using struts2/springframework/hibernate and I'm able to run it using the Vscode + Community Server Connectors + Tomcat.  However, it does not Hot Swap/Auto Reload. Are there additional plugins and/or configuration that I need to use?

Community Server Connectors + Tomcat out of the box it runs the web app but it does not Hot Swap / Reload.